# Random variable w.r.t. to random measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

in the following sketch I reduced a problem which appears in research paper I study.

Assume a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$, a family of probability measures $\mu_g$ on $[0,1]$ and define the following stochastic process $Y:\Omega \times \mathbb{Z} \to [0,1]$ with $Y_g\sim \mu_g$, which indexes a probability kernel $\mathbb{Q}:[0,1] \times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{N}) \to [0,1]$ with $\mathbb{Q}(y,A)=Q_y(A)$, where $Q_y$ defines a probability measure on $\mathbb{N}$.

Further let $X$ be a random variable defined on the same probability space, where we know that for $g \in \mathbb{Z}$ conditioned on $\left\{Y_g=y\right\}$ for $y \in [0,1]$ it holds that $X\sim Q_y$. Denote by $X_{Y_g}$ the random variable X with random distribution $Q_{Y_g}$ at time $g$.

Let $F(y):= \mathbb{E}[X_y]$. How can I show that the following holds:

$\mathbb{E}[X_{Y_g}|Y]=F(Y_g)$

Here we conditioning on the whole process, which means that the index is $Y_g$ is known.

I have trouble to understand how it is possible to perform calculations over a random variable with a distribution which itself is random again. Or how to handle the expectation if conditioning fix the measure. Any hints or suggestions of literature would be very helpful!

Comment: Latex tip - you can use `\to` or `\rightarrow` to get $\to,$ and `\times` to get $\times$. Also check out Detexify for commands for symbols that you might not know.

Comment: You're exactly on the right track here - you know the distribution of $X|Y$ and the distribution of $Y$, so the tower rule is the natural attack for finding the expectation of $X$, which you've done correctly in the comment. As an aside - you define a kernel $Q$ in the question but never really use it. This should be avoided, because it adds needless complexity to your question, making it harder for readers to parse quickly. In fact, in this case one could also argue that explicitly stating the probability space is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for reply, yes true makes it quite harder to read. My aim was actually to describe a similar problem, but due my reduction I simplified my problem way to far. I edit my post and adjusted the setting.